# Read ID from QueryString with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to read an ID from a `QueryString` with jQuery; how can I do it in an efficient way?

Is there any way similar to `$.QueryString`?

Comment: *"Is there any way like $.QueryString etc"* There can be, you just haven't created it yet. There's nothing built into jquery that will do it.

Comment: What "id" are you referring to?  Can you give an example?

Comment: @RocketHazmat myURL?id=123 how can I get 123 with Jquery ???

Comment: @KevinB, Its [this](http://darlesson.com/jquery/querystring) plugin

Comment: @Satpal i'm assuming that the OP has no knowledge that the plugin exists, and it's just coincidence that he named it correctly. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found this it might be helpful for someone

```
(function ($) {
$.QueryString = (function (a) {
    if (a == "") return {};
    var b = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        var p = a[i].split('=');
        if (p.length != 2) continue;
        b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    return b;
})(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'))
})(jQuery);

var id = $.QueryString["id"];
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this, no extra library required:

```
//
// Given a parameter name, returns the corresponding querystring parameter.
//
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
    if (results == null)
        return "";
    else
        return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Sample usage:

```
Id = parseInt(getParameterByName("id")) || 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using [**jQuery - Querystring**](http://darlesson.com/jquery/querystring/) library

```
 var id = $.QueryString("paramter");
```

*Note: it will return null is the query string doesn't exist or the value of the query string if it exists*